# Got an error using ListPreference in Android

Tags: android, settings, android-preferences, listpreference, android-multiselectlistpreference

I have a question about PreferenceScreen in Android Studio. I used MultiSelectListPreference and did not get an error, **however when I used ListPreference, I got an error and does not open setting activity.**

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Time Table Setting">

    <ListPreference
        android:key="Header_List"
        android:entries="@array/setting_header_list"
        android:entryValues="@array/setting_header_values"
        android:title="Display Dates"
        android:summary="Monday to Friday, Saturday or Sunday"/>
</PreferenceCategory>

<Preference
    android:key="Restart"
    android:title="Save"/>
```

> If you have any suggestions, Please help me out. Thank you

**Here is the error message that I've got**

```
2020-03-21 22:06:26.212 14206-14206/com.pythontaro.personaltimetable E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.name, PID: 14206
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.name.appname/com.name.appname.setting.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:225)
    at androidx.preference.Preference.getPersistedString(Preference.java:1686)
    at androidx.preference.ListPreference.onSetInitialValue(ListPreference.java:255)
    at androidx.preference.Preference.onSetInitialValue(Preference.java:1614)
    at androidx.preference.Preference.dispatchSetInitialValue(Preference.java:1587)
    at androidx.preference.Preference.onAttachedToHierarchy(Preference.java:1311)
    at androidx.preference.Preference.onAttachedToHierarchy(Preference.java:1326)
    at androidx.preference.PreferenceGroup.addPreference(PreferenceGroup.java:249)
    at androidx.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:170)
    at androidx.preference.PreferenceInflater.rInflate(PreferenceInflater.java:345)
    at androidx.preference.PreferenceInflater.rInflate(PreferenceInflater.java:346)
    at androidx.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(PreferenceInflater.java:157)
    at androidx.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(PreferenceInflater.java:109)
    at androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:216)
    at androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:361)
    at com.name.appname.setting.SettingsActivity$SettingsFragment.onCreatePreferences(SettingsActivity.java:28)
    at androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreate(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:160)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1255)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1138)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:136)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1989)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2629)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

**This is code in Setting Activity Class**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}}
```

This is code for string value

```
 <!--Setting-->
<string-array name="setting_header_list">
    <item>"Friday(default)"</item>
    <item>"Saturday"</item>
    <item>"Sunday"</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="setting_header_values">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
```

**This is the code of line 225 in SharedPreferencesImpl.java**

```
final StructStat stat;
    try {
        /*
         * Metadata operations don't usually count as a block guard
         * violation, but we explicitly want this one.
         */
        BlockGuard.getThreadPolicy().onReadFromDisk();
        stat = Os.stat(mFile.getPath());
    } catch (ErrnoException e) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: please share the error when you used `ListPreference`.

Comment: I have added error message that I got!

Comment: in `SettingsActivity.java line 28` you are passing key as `hashset` instead `string`. from your stacktrace SharedPreferencesImpl class getString  method accepts only string value. refer this [docs](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java) line number 285.

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace this is the key:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

you are trying to use a `java.util.HashSet` where a `java.lang.String` is in use.

It's at **SharedPreferencesImpl.java:225** when `getString` is being called. This is as far as I can go if you do not share the relevant part of your code.

EDIT

As the asker pointed out here in the comment section, the issue was that double quotation marks were used on string-array items.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added codes for my setting activity class and string value xml.

Comment: @user13024999 you are welcome. I am very interested to know what is line 225 in SharedPreferencesImpl.java ?

Comment: I have added line 225 in SharedPreferenceslmpl.java!

Comment: @user13024999 thank you. I think I asked the wrong question. Can you show me where do you call getString?

Comment: Actually I did not use the method of getString  while using ListPreference. And weird thing is that I could use multiselectlistpreference but not ListPreference.

Comment: @user13024999 it says that the problem is at the onSetInitialValue event. According to the docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference#onSetInitialValue(boolean,%20java.lang.Object)) in order to set the initial value of preference, you need to implement this event. Did you implement this? Or is this implemented?

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestions. I have solved this problem and the issue was using double quatation in string-array items. When I removed these. I worked perfectly. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @user13024999 glad to help and it's great to know the issue has been solved. I have edited my answer to reflect the information you just gave.